# if Activity finish then Service also finish or not?

Tags: android, service

I am newbie please help me and clarify that if Activity finish then Service also finish or not?
for example if activity start Services and then call to second Activity and finish itself then service also finish or remain?
My secinds Question is Start services on splash Activity is good or not?

Comment: Services do not have to finish - depends on the declaration. What is a splash activity?

Comment: it depends if it is a bound service or not.

Comment: splash activity -> don't do them

Comment: Splash Activity means splash Screen that appear only for 3 seconds at the start of an Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services run independently of the place where you start them. So

1. No a service won't stop just because the starting activity finishes
2. An activity is as good a place to start a service as any place that has a `android.content.Context`.

Answer (score 1):

Service finish depends on how Service is started and what does it do.

If a Service is a bound service, that is started via `bindService()`, then after all users of the service have called `unbindService()`, then the service is stopped.

Also, inside the service the value returned from `onStartCommand()` can determine if service would be restored by system if terminated or not.

Finally, a service an explicitly call `stopSelf()` to shutdown itself.

Read more in documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle